# "Expressão ausente após operador unário '--'" ao tentar instalar o postgres pelo docker

Tags: docker

codigo:

```
docker run \
--name postgres \
-e POSTGRES_USER=spirit \
-e POSTGRES_DB=spiritSt \
-e 5432:5432 \
-d \
postgres
```

estava seguindo um tutorial e nele funcionou normal mas no meu pc estou com esse error:

```
No linha:2 caractere:3
+ --name postgres \
+   ~
Expressão ausente após operador unário '--'.
No linha:2 caractere:3
+ --name postgres \
+   ~~~~
Token 'name' inesperado na expressão ou instrução.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Answer (score 1):

O `\` para usar múltiplas linhas não funcione em powershell, troque ele por "acento grave", algo assim:

```
docker run `
--name postgres `
-e POSTGRES_USER=spirit `
-e POSTGRES_DB=spiritSt `
-e 5432:5432 `
-d `
postgres
```

E após isto basta digitar enter duas vezes.

### PowerShell 5+

Se estiver usando PowerShell 5 ou superior e quiser digitar manualmente o comando e suas instruções então pode usar <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> a cada linha nova que desejar inserir

Leia mais em: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_line_editing?view=powershell-6